# ListBox change image on selection

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've got a list box with `SelectionMode` set to `Single` and item template looking like this:

```
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="100" Margin="10" Cursor="Hand" >
                        <Image Source="/Assets/Images/folder_80closed.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}" BorderThickness="0" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Is there any way to change the value of image `Source` property **in XAML** based on if the item is selected or not? Something like pic bellow, where item4 is selected.

[image]

Comment: ValueConverters can be used for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use an Image Style with a DataTrigger on the `IsSelected` property of the current ListBoxItem:

```
<Image HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Image">
            <Setter Property="Source"
                    Value="/Assets/Images/folder_80closed.png"/>

            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger
                    Binding="{Binding IsSelected,
                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}"
                    Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Source"
                            Value="/Assets/Images/some_other_image.png"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what i was looking for. I couldn't figure out how to do that part with RelativeSource AncestorType...  cheers